# HTTPS Apache Configuration for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I was trying to configure https on apache. I did exactly same thing with 12.04, and everything works well. However, when I gets to 14.04, the package apache2-common is not supported for 14.04 and I guess multiple dependencies for 14.04 is not installed properly. I first tried with this configuration file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 1024
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 1024
SSLSessionCache shm:/usr/local/apache2/logs/ssl_cache_shm
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 600

<VirtualHost *:443>
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jason/mapproxy/config.py
WSGIDaemonProcess mapproxy user=jason group=www-data processes=8 threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup mapproxy
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    # if not loaded elsewher

<Directory /home/jason/mapproxy/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLOptions +StrictRequire

<Directory />
    SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>

SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM



SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/Certificate/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/Keys/server.key

SSLVerifyClient none
SSLVerifyDepth 1
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/Certificate/RootCA.crt
SSLProxyEngine off

<IfModule mime.c>
    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert      .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl         .crl
</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

However, it showed first that SSL module is not supported. So I added LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Then, it tell me that Cache is not working, then I deleted all the lines that requires the cache.

After all of that apache is happy, and I could start the apache. However,the https can never be loaded on the browser.

Then, I just try to load the default-ssl.conf. No luck, the web browser still cannot load the webpage.

Hope one could help me with this :-)

Comment: if you install apache2 from package then you only have to enable the ssl module and configured defaul-ssl.conf and enable it too.

Comment: hi @drabo2005 Thank you for your reply. I found that the problem I could not connect to the HTTPS page is that the 443 port is not enabled on the AWS... :-( a stupid mistake. But still, I really appreciate your help!